# SQL ORDER BY Timestamp, identical values

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas

I've got a sql data (MariaDB) with a timestamp index. Sadly there are multiple rows with the indentical timestamp. The best way would be to reject the current data and start using a unique index. Sadly that is not easily done.

When querying like that:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP, DEVICE, VALUE FROM df WHERE DEVICE IN ('A', 'B') ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC
```

The order of the elements with the identical timestamp isn't the same as the order when looking at the complete data without `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC`. I would like to get the data in the same order as written into the SQL data. I am querying in python with pandas and my work around would be to get the complete data prepared with python but that is slower.

Can you help me? I know it should be done different in the first place but maybe there is a work-around.

Fabian

Comment: If your table doesn't have a auto_increment or other column that has a guaranteed order there is no reliable answer,

Comment: As mentioned, rows in an sql have no inherent 'order' other than established by an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL doesn't guarantee the order the data is retrieved in. You need to use another column to force data retrieval in a specific order. don't you have another column you can use in the order by?

Comment: Sadly there isn't another column I could use. But if there is no other way I will add one. If the problem still remains I may have to do some changes to the data to achieve a unique index.